# is the function $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k)}{k3^k}x^k$ continuous at its interval of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k)}{k\cdot 3^k}x^k$$

I found that the interval of convergence is $(-3,3)$ where the endpoints diverge. So is the function continuous at the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

a part of definition of continuity, the function in question has to be *well-defined* at the point of interest. As you are saying, at the endpoints, the function diverges, hence is not well-defined, and thus cannot be continuous.